# How to successfully pass a functional object (or lambda) to the trackbar callback second argument (void*)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, c++11

I have a member function in my class:

```
void handler(int pos, cv::Mat &image)
{
    threshold(image, image, pos, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::imshow("window", this->image); //<-- segfault
}
```

and have a member callback function for createTrackbar:

```
static void on_trackbar(int pos, void* ptr);
```

Then I create this functional object in another member function:

```
std::function<void(int)> bind_handler = std::bind(static_cast<void (my_class::*)(int, cv::Mat&)>(&my_class::handler), this, std::placeholders::_1, img_threshold);
slider = 0;
cv::namedWindow("Test Filter", 1);
cv::createTrackbar("threshold", "Test Filter", &slider, 255, on_trackbar, (void*)&bind_handler);
```

Then in **on_trackbar** I catch the **void* ptr**:

```
std::function<void(int)>* cb = static_cast<std::function<void(int)>* >(ptr);
(*cb)(pos); //<-- segfault
```

Compiled OK.

But when I touch the slider it goes to segmentation fault :(

Also I tried [this code with lambdas](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/1542903/using-c--11-lambdas-with-opencv-3-trackb/) but it segfaults too.

If I take `std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat> thrsh_ptr` to **handler** lambda by [=] it segfaults too.

How to make it correctly?

**UPD:** calls in the handler body.
I found that member `cv::Mat image` becomes 0x0 after `handler` member function was called by `on_trackbar` callback. I check the address of it before `cv::createTrackbar` and inside `handler` body; in both cases it is the same address value.

Comment: `bind_handler` looks like a local variable. You can take its address, but by the time it's actually used, the variable is long destroyed. Why can't `on_trackbar` just take `std::function<void(int)>` in place of `void*`?

Comment: `on_trackbar` would be called by [`cv::createTrackbar`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=createtrackbar#createtrackbar) which requires a specific function prototype; however, you've hit the nail on the head with the local variable thing.

Comment: Normally when we need to use a C-style capllack API in C++, we pass a *pointer to an object* as the `void*` argumeng. The callback itself is a *non-member* or a *static member* function. Then in the callback, we cast the `void*` back to the object type and use it however we like. Thus you want to call `cv::createTrackbar(..., on_trackbar, static_cast<void*>(this))` and inside `on_trackbar` call `(static_cast<my_class*>(data))->handler(pos, image)`.

Comment: But where from I will get this `image`? Every time when I call `cv::imshow(member_mat)` I get a segfault. Before all this code I copyTo data to the member_mat. I don't know why. But passed `int pos` I catch and print without any error.

Comment: "But where from I will get this image?" I don't know. You have a hander that requires an image. Presumably you know how to call it. Perhaps pass it img_threshold. If you don't, call some other handler. Nothing in on_trackbar dictates which handler to call, it's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `bind_handler` is a local variable which ceases to exist immediately following creation of the trackbar. When the library attempts to call the callback, it goes in to your `on_trackbar()` function, passing a pointer to a now-defunct `std::function<>` object, which causes the crash when you attempt to dereference it. That `void* ptr` argument points to a previously-local variable that no longer exists.

What you need to do, as @n.m. mentions, is pass a *pointer to an object* that contains the `cv::Mat`. Inside `bind_handler()`, you cast the `void*` argument back into your object type, and access the image from there, calling any member functions you wish. Your question wasn't quite explicit enough for me to understand your full design, but something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    cv::Mat img_threshold;

    void handler(int pos) {
        cv::threshold(img_threshold, img_threshold, pos, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        cv::imshow("window", img_threshold);
    }

public:
    static void on_trackbar(int pos, void* ptr) {
        MyClass* obj = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(ptr);
        obj->handler(pos);
    }

    void other_function() {
        slider = 0;
        cv::namedWindow("Test Filter", 1);
        cv::createTrackbar("threshold", "Test Filter", &slider, 255, on_trackbar, static_cast<void*>(this));
    }
};
```